# how to catch exception of ssh_options_set function

Tags: c++, exception, libssh

I have this function which can handle a connection to ssh.

```
connectSession()
{
    std::string _ErrMsg;
    MyException errMsg;
    int port = 22;
    try
    {
        if (my_ssh_session == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Error creating ssh session" << std::endl;
            throw MyException("Error in creating session");
        }

        try
        {
            ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, (const void*)(authentication.ip));
            ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, (const void*)(authentication.userName));
            ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    
        int rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
        if (rc != SSH_OK) {
            std::cout << "Error with connecting" << std::endl;
            _ErrMsg = ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
            ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
            throw MyException(_ErrMsg);
        }
        rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, (const char*)(authentication.pw));
        if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) {
            std::cout << "Authentication failed " << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session) << std::endl;
            _ErrMsg = ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
            ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
            ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
            throw invalid_argument(_ErrMsg);
        }
    }
    catch (const invalid_argument& e)
    {
        throw_with_nested(invalid_argument(e.what()));
    }
}
```

I have put `my_ssh_session = ssh_new();` in my constructor.
 I want to be able to catch exception whenever an exception occurs on `ssh_options_set`( for example when `my_ssh_session = ssh_new();` is commented it throws an error.)  how can I do that?

Comment: As from the docs [here](https://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__session.html#ga7a801b85800baa3f4e16f5b47db0a73d) it looks like these functions are a plain c API and won't ever throw any exeptions at all. You should handle the return code to check for errors instead.

Comment: Some more suggestions: Get rid of C-style casts unless you are sure that you need them. The above probably doesn't need them. Further, it may make sense to wrap all `ssh_*` functions in a small wrapper that just raises an exception on failure. You can keep your actual code cleaner that way.  Lastly, consider codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: you mean the casting to `const void *` ? @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: and about the thing you said about wrapping all functions in a wrapper to just rise one exception, what if I want function not to continue after for example `my_ssh_session` is null at the first place? @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: Casts - yes, even if the conversion wasn't performed implicitly, there are C++ casts that probably fit better (`static_cast`, I guess). Concerning the pointer being null, I'd try to avoid having a non-null pointer. So, the function that allocates either returns a non-null value or throws an exception, similar to `new`.